# scrolling into z axis with css or javascript with image layered one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

There are four images on a page in the same place. Only the top image is visible. The 3 images beneath it is not visible.

If the user scroll into the image, they will see the second image and first image will go out of screen. The animation will be like first image will getting bigger towards the four corner of the screen and eventually fade away.

User will get the feeling of moving towards Z axis to see the second image beneath first image. This animation will continue till last image.

All these image will point to different links. User can click on the image link or scroll.

Is css 3d transform the only option or any javascript plugin to assist this goal?

Example:
https://www.format.com/2016?ref=webdesignernews.com#

Comment: Here's [another example](https://gist.github.com/mattbaker/2153965) -- maybe a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to write an entire 3d CSS project for you, but here is how it can be done. http://eng.wealthfront.com/2012/03/22/scrolling-z-axis-with-css-3d-transforms/